# Get url from a wp post page

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get a specific .m3u8 url from a JW embed post in a wordpress site.

The page contains this block of code when rendered.

```
....
"streamer":"",
"provider":"",
"file":"http://mysite.com:1935/live/mp4:folder/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8"}},
{"type":"download","config":{"streamer":"","provider":""}}
]});
```

What I am trying to do is how to take the url part

```
http://mysite.com:1935/live/mp4:folder/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```

and store it in a variable so that I can pass it on with my rss code.

What php function can get this URL from a block of code?

Thanks

Comment: data seems to be in `json` form, see [json_decode](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that block of code is inside a javascript block.

Comment: its looks like json response see this [page](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/parse-json/) It would help you to parse json in php.